# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 DateTime Format on View?

Tags: datetime, format

I am trying to format the DateTime to Just display just date with out time.

Can any one suggest on that please?

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor("", String.Format("{0:dddd, MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.DOB))
```

Comment: use shortDate Conversion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Conversion On View Use this one..

```
@Html.DisplayTextFor("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.DOB))
```

and for Conversion in ViewModel you can simply use this..

```
(DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: No over load Method for DisplayTextfor Takes two Arguments

Comment: anyone facing this issue check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29742649/2218697)

Answer (score 2):

You should try `@Html.Raw`

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.DOB))
```

Or you can do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DOB)
```

and then in your model class have this attribute on the property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to be quick and easy

```
 @Html.FormatValue(item.PostDate,"{0:dd-mm-yyyy}")
```