# Checking if the value of type DateTime is null in view and showing blank if null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, nullable

From my controller I have passed value module to view

```
    public ActionResult Details(long id, string owner)
    {
        var module = _ownedModuleRepository.GetModuleDetails(id, owner);

        return View(module);
    }
```

I've shown the value it contains in view as follows

```
    <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd>@Model.Id</dd>

    <dt>Module ID</dt>
    <dd>@Model.ModuleId</dd>

     <dt>Owner</dt>
    <dd>@Model.Owner</dd>

    <dt>Module Type</dt>
    <dd>@Model.TypeName</dd>

    <dt>Module Kind</dt>
    <dd>@Model.KindName</dd>

    <dt>Ownership Start Date</dt>
    <dd>@Model.Start</dd>

    <dt>Ownership End Date</dt>
    <dd>@Model.End</dd>

    @foreach (var properties in Model.Properties)
    {
        <dt>Property Name</dt>
        <dd>@properties.Name</dd>
        <dt>Property Value</dt>
        <dd>@properties.Value</dd>
    }
```

Currently **@Model.End** is null, it is of DateTime type and I had set it to be nullable in viewmodel.
Since it is null, this is what i'm getting in view

[image]

As you can see, the value of Ownership End Date is taking the value of Property Name from below. How can I set it to empty if the *@Model.End is null*?

**Edit 1:**

My model

```
public class OwnedModuleDetails
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string ModuleId { get; set; }

    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public string KindName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime? End { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Method from the repository

```
     public OwnedModuleDetails GetModuleDetails(long id, string owner)
        {
// ReSharper disable ImplicitlyCapturedClosure
            var module = (_dbSis.OwnedModules.Where(t => t.Id == id).Select(m => new OwnedModuleDetails
// ReSharper restore ImplicitlyCapturedClosure
            {
                Id = id,
                ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
                TypeName = m.ModuleType.TypeName,
                KindName = m.ModuleType.ModuleKind.KindName,
                Owner = owner,
                Start = m.Start,
                End = m.End,
                Properties = m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(
                    x => new Property { Name = x.Property.Name, Value = x.Value })
            }));

            return (module.FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

Comment: It's weird how you could get a string value inside a `DateTime?` type. Are you sure that the `End` property is `DateTime?` ? Where is this `MicrophoneArrayRackModuleId` coming from?

Comment: It is set to date and time, I have put my Model as an edit, also the method controllers calls in repository

Comment: Where is this `MicrophoneArrayRackModuleId` coming from? You cannot possibly get such output for a DateTime property.

Comment: My model has `IEnumerable<Property> Properties` Property class contains **Name** (string) and **Value** (string), `MicrophoneRackModuleId` is one of the `Proerties` **Name**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a space:

```
<dt>Ownership End Date</dt>
<dd>
    @if (Model.End != null)
    {
        @Model.End
    }
    else
    {
        @:&nbsp;
    }
</dd>
```

Comment: For first option I get error `There is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'system.web.Ihtmlstring'` for second option right in **:** of `@:&nbsp;` it says `@ must be followed by valid code block`. I tried removing **@:** but in browser it shows `Ownership End Date` as `if (Model.End != null) { } else {   }`

Comment: The `if` statement should be prefixed with `@`.

Comment: yea, I forgot. Thanks, it worked. So if you have a null value then value from next item comes to the previous item? Like in my case.

Comment: No, it's a CSS issue with your `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags. If it is empty apparently the browser displays the next one. You should try fixing your CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue once, when user inserted null value in date column.

Which lead to this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value`

To solve this instead of `DisplayFor` just use below code in your view , so if the column value is null it will display Date is Empty

```
 <td>
            
@(item.Startdate.HasValue ? item.Startdate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "Date is Empty")

</td>
```

Further reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331902/mvc-view-nullable-date-field-formatting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684015/formatting-nullable-datetime-fields-in-strong-typed-view?rq=1) for model

Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use C# null coalescing operator:

```
@(Model.End?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ?? "Date is Empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't a ternary operation work here:

```
@(Model.End != null ? Model.End.ToString() : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@model.date.toString() == "01/01/0001"
```

After converting datetime into string you're now able to compare DateTime value.